# MFC SDI app - How can I destroy and re-create the single document?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a native C++ MFC/Win32 app running on Windows.  For various reasons, I'd like to be able to re-instantiate the document object.  i.e. delete the existing document object, create a new instance, and drop that new instance in place of the previous one.

I'm sure there's a specific process for doing this to ensure everything in the framework is setup properly afterwards.  Does anyone have experience with doing this successfully?  Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Simply reload the document... what Special things do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm able to load the document without issue.  What I'm asking about is destroying the document instance and re-creating it and then making sure the framework is "happy" with the replacement document.

Comment: There is no Need for a replacement. All internal Variables don't Need a new init Phase ater the doc is created.

It is all about your Content of the class and you have all control over it!

Again: Why do you think you needa recreate?

Comment: I understand you don't feel there is a need to do this; what I'm asking though is not why or whether this should be done, but how one could go about doing it successfully.

I'd like to re-instantiate the document to get a "clean start" as opposed to having reset/clear methods get called for file>>new or file>>open to set variables back to their default values or deal with loading older files which don't serialize in some variables and so then have to rely on a method to clear those out.  I think it just might be cleaner to start fresh with a new doc instance.

Comment: With MDI you get a clean/new instance of the doc with each opened or new file.  With SDI you have to rely on cleanup functions to reset things back to their defaults since the same doc is re-used.  I'd like to have the MDI approach and get a fresh new doc instance each time just in an SDI context.  Hopefully this addresses your questions.  But back to the original question, how would one go about doing this?

Comment: There is no way to do this. The document is always reused in the SDI. If the document closes the SDI application exists.